# Different versions of a pkgdef file per Visual Studio version

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

We have a situation that other than the "main" `.pkgdef` file of the extension, we have another file which performs additional registration. This registration is different between the different versions of Visual Studio. An example of one such file is:

```
[$RootKey$\CLSID\{some guid}]
"CodeBase"="$PackageFolder$\MyUtility.vs11.dll"
...
```

with different values and GUIDs for other Visual Studios.

Until now, we had an external installer (msi) copy the correct additional `.pkgdef` file next to the main one, e.g. for Visual Studio 2012:

```
MyExtension.pkgdef
MyExtensions.vs11.pkgdef
...
```

We're looking to switch to VSIX deployment, but keeping a single VSIX, and a single extension (instead of building one for each version of Visual Studio).

The question is: since during package registration (devenv /setup) Visual Studio will process *all* `.pkgdef` files sequentially, is there a way to specify just the specific `.pkgdef` file(s) to register?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, not currently supported. Vote here:

Conditions support for  section of VSIX manifest

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6364594-conditions-support-for-content-section-of-vsix-m

Comment: Thanks,  Carlos, I guessed as much. We're "solving" the problem by manually building the vsix (zip file) in a post build step...